What is the purpose of the "Webform (default)" text format?
Recently I've found that the Webform module provides a text format named "Webform (Default)". I admit that I do not have a rich experience with this complex module, so I have some questions:
This text format is hidden. It is not available in the list of text formats provided by the common interface used for configuring text formats: /admin/config/content/formats. How can this text format be configured (the security review module complains about it).
During the development of my Webform I was not even aware about its existence. When controls are placed on a web form no control configuration options seem to mention it. Then, when the webform is activated and used by web users the controls placed on the webform accept only plain text. There is no option near the controls that allow me to switch between Plain text and CK Editor.
What is the purpose of this text format?
Thank you.

I would also like to know more about this. I just found a side-effect: Registered users in my project can only use plain text. Having only one text format meant that Drupal didn't display the text format select. Now they have this second text format, although it's hidden, and they see a select with only the plain text option in it.


The Webform module provided a custom instance of the CKEditor, which
added additional dependencies and maintenance challenges. The Webform
module now provides a default hidden 'webform_default' text format
that leverages Drupal core's editor and CKEditor modules.
The new default 'webform_default' text format is completely hidden
from all instances of the text format element and the admin UI. The
approach allows the new default 'webform_default' text format to be
backward compatible and fully maintained by the Webform module.
(https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3322552)

Additional info I got in the Drupal Slack reagrding this:

I believe that users can choose a different format in global webform
settings?  I think a rock solid upgrade path was part of the
rationality behind the default format.  It's a lot harder to support
ckeditor5 in "wild west" mode than it is to support a known-in-advance
configuration. For folks that choose their own adventure, Webform
upgrades won't touch your format.
(Luke Alan Leber)

